# Table Structure for IVR Menu(DTMF keys)

Tags: asterisk, telephony, ivr

I am developing a SMS based menu which will work on DTMF keys(0 - 9) Now this menu will have nine levels and their further menu likewise.

Now I want that all information about menus should be available from databse.

Currently I plan to create the table structure like following

menuid, menutext, parent-menuid , menulevel

but it's not fullfilling the complete requirements. Any idea for table structure for typical IVR menu which show menu based on DTMF?

Regards,
imran

Comment: you're going to need to be a lot more specific how can we help you if you do not actually post what your requirements are, its all very well saying it doesn't meet them but in order for anyone to help you're going to need to provide the relevant information

Comment: I agree with @krystan, you are not providing enough information in you question to provide an answer. I have never heard of an "SMS based menu" that uses DTMF.  SMS does not look for DTMF input and is simply looking for text in a response. If you want to develop a self service application using SMS they usually expect text as the response (Ex: Send the message "GO" to register for this application) and chat bots are used on the receiving side to process the message and perform the appropriate action/response.

Answer (score 0):

Basic structure like folloing:

```
create table ivr(
id serial,
name varchar(40),
go_timeout_type smallint,
go_timeout bigint,
go_invalid_type smallint,
go_invalid bigint);

create table ivr_choices(
 id serial,
 ivr_id bigint,
 choice varchar(5),
 go_onchoice_type smalling,
 go_onchoice bigint
);

create unique index ivr_choices_get on ivr_choices(ivr_id,choice);
```

In this example u code in _type what destination u have go. For sub-ivr u put dest_type=ivr, dest=ivr_id.